# AVG of an TIMEDIFF having a GROUP BY and a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to summarize a KPI that uses two tables. Basically is an t1.ID, t2.ID and a TIMESTAMPDIFF between date fields from the two tables, as follows (ps.: the code itself is a little bit longer - I kept only the essential below to represent the problem):

```
SELECT `ticket`.`id` AS `Ticket`, `article`.`change_by` AS `UserID`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `ticket`.`create_time`, min(`article`.`create_time`)) AS `TimeDiff`
FROM `article`, `ticket`
WHERE `ticket`.`id` = `article`.`ticket_id`
GROUP BY `Ticket`, `UserID`
```

So, the result is this:

```
Ticket           |UserID|TimeDiff
_________________________________
2019080141000014 |     7|       2
2019080141000023 |    11|       1
2019080141000032 |     7|       2
2019080141000041 |     7|       3
2019080141000051 |     7|      83
2019080141000069 |    11|       1
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
UserID|TimeDiff
_______________
     7|      90
    11|       2
```

How could I do this?

EDIT: The point that is messing my head is that `create_time` calculation is made *per ticket* and the final result I want is a *userID* GROUP BY.

Comment: Is `min(\`article\`.\`create_time\`)` supposed to be over all tickets, or just tickets created by that particular user?

Comment: Your desired result looks more like a `SUM` than an `AVG`

Comment: SELECT `Ticket`, `article`, `UserID`, SUM(`TimeDiff`) AS `TimeDiff`  from (
 SELECT `ticket`.`id` AS `Ticket`, `article`.`change_by` AS `UserID`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `ticket`.`create_time`, min(`article`.`create_time`)) AS `TimeDiff`
FROM `article`, `ticket`
WHERE `ticket`.`id` = `article`.`ticket_id`
GROUP BY `Ticket`, `UserID`) org_table GROUP BY UserID

Comment: Note, when constructing sample data, it's friendlier to use ticket ids like 14, 23, and 32, instead of 2019080141000014, 
2019080141000023, and
2019080141000032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT userid
     , SUM(timediff) total 
  FROM
     ( SELECT t.id Ticket
            , a.change_by UserID
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.create_time, min(a.create_time)) TimeDiff
         FROM article a
         JOIN ticket t
           ON t.id = a.ticket_id
        GROUP 
           BY Ticket
            , UserID
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY userid
```

Comment: Your code did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per user, then that should be the `group by`.  And an aggregation query would normally have aggregation functions.

Your aggregation has a problem with `a.change_by`.  It is neither aggregated nor in the `GROUP BY`.

So, I think you want:

```
SELECT a.change_by AS UserID,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.create_time, a.create_time)) AS TimeDiff
FROM article a JOIN
     ticket t
     ON t.id = a.ticket_id
WHERE a.create_time = (SELECT MIN(a2.create_time)
                       FROM article a2
                       WHERE a2.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
                      )
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Four other points:

- Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Embarrassing use of backticks just makes the query hard to read.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- In MySQL 8+, you can express this more concisely using window functions.

Comment: Perfect about the proper use of standard JOIN. I'm re-learning SQL (10 years without using it) and sometimes I forget to use it.
About the backticks, it's the default use for MySQL queries in Metabase. I should remove them before posting here, you're right.
About table aliases, same thing as the JOIN use.

About the code, didn't work (all "timediffs" were zeroes) but it helped me to understand when you used "a" and "a2" to reference "article" differently.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you want to remove the `Ticket` field from the `GROUP BY` statement.

Then you can simply wrap your select in `AVG()`

```
SELECT `ticket`.`id` AS `Ticket`, `article`.`change_by` AS `UserID`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `ticket`.`create_time`, min(`article`.`create_time`)) AS `TimeDiff`,
AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `ticket`.`create_time`, min(`article`.`create_time`))) AS `TimeDiff_AVG`
FROM `article`, `ticket`
WHERE `ticket`.`id` = `article`.`ticket_id`
GROUP BY `UserID`
```

Comment: Any why is the downvote?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it's unreadable nonsense.